# UITableViewCell with 2 accessory types

Tags: iphone, uitableview, accessorytype

I would like to make a `UITableViewCell` with one label and two accessory types:

- Unselected cells should display a `UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton` accessory.
- The selected cell should display both the `UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator` and the `UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton` accessories.

The only way I know how to do this is by using an image for the selected cell's accessory view. Is there an alternative way to do this?

Comment: I don't think this is really possible. You'll probably have to approximate one of the accessories with an image you put there yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    selectedIndex = indexPath //selectedIndex is a property

}
```

Then in

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
//usual cell stuff

    if(indexPath == selectedIndex) 
        [cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator];
    else
        [cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton];


}
```

So the trick is just to keep a reference to the selected cell and set the indicator accordingly.

Note that you might want to test if the cell is already selected before setting the selectedIndex, in that case you should set selectedIndex = nil.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't want one accessory type or the other. I want both, for the row that is selected.

Comment: Ahh ok, that was not what you were asking before the edit. The disclosureIndicator and -button occupy the same space so I guess you would have to go with the custom button solution provided above. Add it to the cell, and set [disclosureBtn setHidden:YES] or NO in the cellForRowAtIndexPath.. if(selectedIndex == indexPath).

Comment: ITableViewCellAccessories aren't views. How would you define them in the custom UITableViewCell? One of them as an image/button, or is there another way to do it?

Comment: Of course, it's a button, as you said, and as the end of the key UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton indicates. Thanks!

Comment: I still didn't get what I need. I need the UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator to be on the left side. How can I achieve that? I can see it isn't a button this time, so I can't add a button and set it as UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator.

Answer (score 2):

Make a custom `UITableViewCell` (numerous tutorials and examples online and also in [the documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewCell_Class/Reference/Reference.html)).

Comment: I know how to make a custom UITableViewCell with as many UILabels or UIImages as I would like, but I don't know how to make it with 2 accessory types in the same cell. Could you please send me a link to a tutorial where this is done? I tried to find it, but I didn't succeed.